# LibGDX/Android development: Setting default orientation for accelerometer

Tags: java, android, libgdx, orientation, accelerometer

I am creating an Android game that uses the accelerometer for X-axis and Y-axis movement in landscape orientation. The X-axis works as expected, however the Y-axis is causing an issue.

For the Y-axis to work properly, the Y-axis needs to be at 0 (The phone is perfectly screen-up.) This is an issue because I don't expect users to be hunched over their phones to play properly.

I attempted to correct this by taking the initial reading of the Y-axis orientation and subtracting that from the following Y-axis readings, but if the user begins the game at -10 (Phone screen directly facing them) the phone will not register any further tilting back.

Does anyone know a better way to handle this situation? Thank you all for the help thus far!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Check out [Allowing both landscape options and accelerometer with libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749588/allowing-both-landscape-options-and-accelerometer-with-libgdx)

and [a fix for accelerometer reading](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2041)